# Is it possible to link dynamically winsock2 into my c/c++ program

Tags: c, windows, dll, lib

I want to add winsock2.lib into my program, but don't want it to be included into the final executable. Is there any way for me to dynamically load the dll associated with winsock2 ?
If no, is there any dll (included with windows) that can achieve the same goal ? (tcp networking)

Comment: *but don't want it to be included into the final executable* what you mean under this ? and i never listen about *winsock2.lib* - this is custom lib ?

Comment: I’m guessing you mean “ws2_32.lib”? Anyway, the answer is simple: sure! [You can just use the DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=vs-2017) instead of the static library.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to loadlibrary of ws2_32.dll

Thanks to Konrad Rudolph for the solution !